# The type does not include any accessible constructors

Tags: c#, wpf, constructor

Why do I get that compile error when I set the constructor this way:

```
  public class Castle
  {
        public Castle (bool mark, string description)
        {
            CastleMarked = mark;
            CastleDescription = description;
        }

        bool CastleMarked {get; set;}
        string CastleDescription {get; set;}
  }
```

And then initialize it from other place this way:

```
Castle cas1 = new Castle(true,"Stone");
```

Comment: Your code does not compile for other reasons, and will not give that error.  Please show an actual example.

Comment: What aren't you showing us here? There are mistakes in the code, since you haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and the CastleMarked and CastleDescription properties don't have types. Your constructor looks okay, but given how incorrect the rest of the code is we can't really comment usefully.

Comment: I just skipped the interface implementation and forgot the types of my variables because I've renamed them for easier interpretation. Sorry.

Comment: `CastleMarked bool` wrong order ;p it should be `bool CastleMarked`

Comment: In moments like this you just want to hind behind a rock. My problem consisted in a binding that was named incorrectly. Sorry guys! By the error description I focused on the constructor.

Comment: @Sturm as I said before "sometimes errors cause another errors, so correct them first and then check out the rest." :-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you haven't implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

And what is this:

```
CastleMarked  {get; set;}
```

where is type of property?

**EDIT:**

add `public` before `class`

**EDIT2:**

Have you checked that or are you only editing your question ;p?

Because this code works fine:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Castle
    {
        public Castle(bool mark, string description)
        {
            CastleMarked = mark;
            CastleDescription = description;
        }

        bool CastleMarked { get; set; }
        string CastleDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Castle cas1 = new Castle(true, "Stone");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sometimes errors cause another errors, so correct them first and then check the rest. Check out my modification.

Answer (score 0):

Implement add the methods of the interface. Or remove the Inotifypropertychanged. Also fix the properties like `private string property { get; set; }`